# Column xyz data to grid for plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a very large amount of data that needs plotting which is stored in 3 columns as xyz data. I need to convert the column data into a grid so I can easily plot it with contourf in matplotlib and I was wondering whether there was a function to do this as the code I've written myself is very slow?

i.e.

```
x y z

1 1 10

1 2 12

2 1 14

2 2 16
```

to a grid like this:

```
10 12

14 16
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy is kind of smart with this. You could just read the columns in separate arrays and do:

```
import numpy

idx1 = numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 1])
idx2 = numpy.array([0, 1, 0, 1])
data = numpy.array([10, 12, 14, 16])

grid = numpy.zeros(len(data)/2, 2)
grid[idx1, idx2] = data

>>>grid
array([[ 10.,  12.],
      [ 14.,  16.]])
```

Keep in mind  that indexing starts from 0 so if yours starts from 1 you need to decrement 1 from each element.

Comment: What if the first two columns don't contain consecutive integers or no integers at all?

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but there is something wrong with the `numpy.zeros` usage, the (1st) argument it gets should be a shape, like `(2,2)`. This doesn't currently working, so I'm downvoting :/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your data is contained in `data.txt`. The following code will print out the required parts of the data in correct order.

Assuming that `data.txt` has `x` and `y` coordinates in consecutive lines:

```
data.txt
x y z
1 1 10
1 2 12
2 1 14
2 2 16

def extract(filepath):
    f = open(filepath)
    f.readline() # to read out the first line that says "x y z"
    while 1:
        x = f.readline().strip().split()[-1]
        y = f.readline().strip().split()[-1]
        print x, y
```

Note that this will end with an Exception when all the contents of the file have been processed (but all the values will still be printed). To avoid this, replace `f = open(filepath)` with `with open(filepath) as f:`

However, if `data.txt` is not structured like that, then you need to take advantage of the first two numbers in each line:

```
data.txt
x y z
1 1 10
2 1 14
1 2 12
2 2 16

from collections import defaultdict
def extract(filepath):
    coords = defaultdict(dict)
    f = open(filepath)
    f.readline() # to read out the first line that says "x y z"
    for line in f:
        id, axis, val = map(int, line.strip().split())
        coords[id][axis] = val

    for i in sorted(coords):
        print coords[i][1], coords[i][2]
```

Hope this helps