# Numpy: convert xyzV table to a grid

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have this text file I can read with `numpy.loadtxt` into a 2D array:

```
 X   Y   Z   V
-30 -15 -25  2
-29 -15 -25  2.1
-28 -15 -25  2.2
 .   .   .    .
 .   .   .    .
+29 -15 -25  2.1
+30 -15 -25 -2.0
-30 -14 -25  2   # now iterating X values while Y=-14
-29 -14 -25  2.1
-28  .   .   2.2
 .   .   .    .
 .   .   .    .
+29 -13 -25  2.1
+30 -13 -25 -2.0 # now iterating X values while Y=-13, and so on...
 .   .   .    .
 .   .   .    .
 .   .   .    .
 .   .   .    .
```

The ranges of X, Y and Z are not necessarily integers, and as illustrated above not the same in all axes. I want to create a grid out of this data, i.e to get arrays such that:

```
>>> np.shape(V)
(61,31,51)
>>> np.shape(x)
(61,)
>>> np.shape(y)
(31,)
>>> np.shape(z)
(51,)
```

I saw an almost [identical question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114301/column-xyz-data-to-grid-for-plotting), but its clear to see that the answer there rely on the fact that the `X` & `Y` columns contain integers starting from a known, and positive number.

Comment: It's difficult to answer with an incomplete example. Why don't you provide a complete example (without `...`) and which would have a small final shape `(2,3,4)` or `(3,4,5)`?

Comment: `its clear to see that the answer there rely on the fact that the X & Y columns contain integers starting from a known, and positive number.` If the grid is uniform, you can transform this problem into one where the X and Y columns are integers counting up from zero by subtracting the minimum element and dividing by the grid spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table is consistent with the repetition of X,Y & Z values, you can use `np.unique` and `len` to calculate the shape the resulting array should get. Here's a complete code that's working:

```py
import numpy as np

table = np.loadtxt("potential.csv", delimeter=",", skiprows=1)
x = np.unique(table[:,0])
y = np.unique(table[:,1])
z = np.unique(table[:,2])

potential = np.zeros((len(x), len(y), len(z)))
for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(x)):
            index = k + j*len(x)+ i*len(y)*len(x)
            potential[k,j,i] = table[index, 3]
```

`np.reshape` doesn't fit in this case. To reach the correct `index` in the 1 dimensional array of `table`, you have to use the fact that Y values are changed after all X values were iterated. Hence we multiply `j` by the length of `x`. Same goes with Z indices in relationship with X and Y lengths.